# How do I solve the following differential equation (It's not seperable)?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to Solve the following equation: find the solution $y:(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of $y'=\dfrac{y}{1-x^2}+x$?

It is not separable and I have no other Tools to solve it.

Comment: Integrating factor? Power series?

Comment: It's a linear equation.

Comment: Your equation is of the form dy/dx+P(x) y = Q(x), so you should use an integrating factor

Comment: Stop making redundant edits to your post to bump your question! I have had this question open for 5 mins and you are constantly changing irrelevant details.

Comment: I answered to your question. Hope I did not do any mistake, it was pretty harsh to write down all these symbolisms, haha ! Hope I helped you.

Comment: @qmd agreed. -1 for the constant edits to bump the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract $ \frac {y(x)}{1-x^2} $ from both sides :

$ \frac {dy(x)}{dx} + \frac {y(x)}{x^2-1} = - \frac {-x^3 + x}{x^2-1}$

Let $ m(x) = e^{\int \frac {1}{x^2-1} dx } = \frac {\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{x+1}} $

Then multiplay both sides by m(x) and substitute : $ \frac {\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{x+1}(x^2-1)} = \frac {d}{dx} \frac {\sqrt{-x+1}}{\sqrt{x+1}} $. Apply the reverse product rule : $ g \frac{df}{dx} + f \frac{dg}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}(fg) $ to the left side of the equation above and integrate both sides :

$\int \frac {\sqrt{-x+1}y(x)}{\sqrt{x+1}} dx= \int - \frac {\sqrt{-x+1}(-x^3 + x)}{\sqrt{x+1}(x^2-1)}dx $

You will then get :

$ \frac {\sqrt{-x+1}y(x)}{\sqrt{x+1}} = - sin^1(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{2}}) + \frac{1}{2}(x-2)\sqrt{-x^2 +1} + c $

Divide both sides by m(x) that we defined above and you get :

$ y(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x+1}(- sin^1(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{2}}) + \frac{1}{2}(x-2)\sqrt{-x^2 +1} + c)}{\sqrt{-x+1}} $

This is the solution to your differential equation, I hope I didn't do any typing mistake while writing it down !

Comment: How do you obtain $m(x)$?

Comment: By integrating the function of which y(x) is multiplied with after the subtraction : $ \frac{1}{x^2-1} $ . Picked it up on spot for the following calculations on the differential